# Lookup range to find name, return specific text if cell contains the name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

trying to write a formula that will lookup a range based on text in column A and return what the person is working on. For example, I want the formula to look at cell A1 (John), and find if John exists in the range. If he does, then I want it to return what he's working on (Deep Fry Station). Or if it's Wayne, I want it to return "Packer".

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  What are your results?

Comment: Please put the data as text in the Original Post using [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42791635/edit) so we do not need to recreate the data.

Answer (score 2):

Use TRIM, MID, SUBSTITUTE and REPT to retrieve the 'piece' that you want with wrapping IFERRORs to compensate for no matches.

[image]